# AVWeakReferencingDelegateStorage: delegate serialization queue

Tags: ios, ios10

I am currently running into an issue new to my iOS application since the iOS 10 update. The issue has only happened on devices with iOS 10 and above. The full crash log is as follows:

```
Crashed: <AVWeakReferencingDelegateStorage: 0x170229fc0> delegate serialization queue
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x18f8121e8 _os_object_retain + 72
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18f8111c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x18f822584 _dispatch_non_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
3  AVFoundation                   0x1980e33ec -[AVWeakReferencingDelegateStorage getRetainedDelegate:retainedDelegateQueue:] + 168
4  AVFoundation                   0x1980e3240 -[AVWeakReferencingDelegateStorage delegate] + 36
5  AVFoundation                   0x1980ce244 -[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _handleRemoteQueueOperation:] + 76
6  AVFoundation                   0x1980ce168 __47-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _updateRemoteQueue:]_block_invoke + 100
7  CoreMedia                      0x1932a0da8 __FigRemoteOperationReceiverCreateMessageReceiver_block_invoke + 260
8  CoreMedia                      0x1932c0020 __FigRemoteQueueReceiverSetHandler_block_invoke.2 + 216
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18f8111c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f81e008 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 576
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f82a648 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f813164 _dispatch_source_invoke + 820
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f81f278 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 468
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f8149a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f81f278 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 468
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f8149a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f8202ac _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_item + 248
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x18f826b0c _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 816
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18fa19174 _pthread_wqthread + 948
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18fa18db4 start_wqthread + 4
```

I have found in my code where exactly the code crashes, but I do now know what is causing it to crash on devices with iOS 10. 
P.S. it does not crash on all iOS 10+ devices.

The code is below:

```
- (void)forwardToResultsVC:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    self.successfulTestResults = results;

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [self.petTest updateTestWithTestElementParameters:results];
    [localContext MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kTestAnalyzeSeguge sender:nil];

    // Log successful test and time it took to take (Parse)
    NSDate *testCompleteDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeToTakeTest = [testCompleteDate timeIntervalSinceDate:self.testStartDate];
    NSDictionary *params = @{ kPetnosticsAnalyticsTimeToTakeSuccesfulTest : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timeToTakeTest]};
    [PFAnalytics trackEvent:kPetnosticsAnalyticsTestSuccesfullyCompleted dimensions:params];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kTestResultsSeguge]) {
        SPResultsViewController *resultsVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        resultsVC.test = self.petTest;
        resultsVC.ogHarrisFoundPointsImage = self.ogHarrisFoundPointsImage;
        resultsVC.foundTestPointsImage = self.foundTestPointsImage;
        resultsVC.analysisImage = self.analysisImage;
        resultsVC.croppedStripImage = self.croppedStripImage;
        resultsVC.test = self.petTest;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kTestAnalyzeSeguge]) {
        SPAnalyzingViewController *analyzingVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        analyzingVC.pet = self.pet;
        analyzingVC.test = self.petTest;
        analyzingVC.ogHarrisFoundPointsImage = self.ogHarrisFoundPointsImage;
        analyzingVC.foundTestPointsImage = self.foundTestPointsImage;
        analyzingVC.analysisImage = self.analysisImage;
        analyzingVC.croppedStripImage = self.croppedStripImage;
        analyzingVC.backingCard = self.backingCard;
        if (self.testMethod == nil) {
            self.testMethod = @"Cup";
        }
        analyzingVC.testMethod = self.testMethod;
    } 
}
```

The segue then prompts the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self saveTestUploadImage];
}

- (void)saveTestUploadImage
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        UIImage *debugImage = self.foundTestPointsImage;
        NSData *testImageData = nil;
        if (debugImage) {
            [debugImage saveImageTofileName:@"testImage.jpg"];
            testImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(debugImage, 1);
        }
        if ([testImageData length] > 0) {
            PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"testImage.jpg" data:testImageData];
            [self uploadTestDataWithImage:imageFile];
        } else {
            // No Test Image Data... hmm...
            [PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"SPTestNoImageFound"];
            [self uploadTestDataWithImage:nil];
        }
    });
}
```

However, it crashes prior to saveTestUploadImage is called.
Any ideas? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`in your trace, did you add the appropriate authorization to your plist file ? `NSCameraUsageDescription`, `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, and especially `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` that does seem to make app crash witouth the correct crash information.

Comment: This is a very good guess. We had to track down a similar problem, and we were astonished to find that it was because we hadn't specified one of the **Privacy: ** strings in the plist.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, since it does not happen on all iOS10 devices and does not happen every time (it comes and goes), I cannot test this theory. The app was release prior to iOS 10 update on the app store. Prior to iOS 10, privacy was taken care of automatically, do you think that the new iOS confuses itself with older apps?

Comment: In my case the app was always crashing on a new install on an ios10 device. And I'm pretty sure it didn't crash on device where the app was already installed and launched before an update to iOS10.

Comment: I was able to test the theory and it was not the case. Thank you though. I have solved it, however. It was a threading issue.